# How to select all radio button by default inside loop in react

Tags: reactjs, radio-button

I am new to react, I want to select all radio buttons inside map loop.I am setting defaultChecked={index}, but it only selects the last radio button and the same is true for checked prop. Kindly help me.

```
availableCars.map((item, index) => (
  <div className="item" key={index}>
    <div className="carbox">
      <div className="bluebg" />
      <div className="choosedesc">
        <h4>{item.vehicle_name}</h4>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div className="selecttrip">
          {!roundTrip || !oneWayTrip ? (
            <React.Fragment>
              {selectTripTypeError}
            </React.Fragment>
          ) : null}
          <label className="radiowrap">
            Round Trip{' '}
            <span className="blue">
              {item.rt_price}
              {item.currency == 'EUR'
                ? '€'
                : 'GBP'
                  ? '£'
                  : item.currency}
            </span>
            <input
              type="radio"
              value={item.rt_price}
              defaultChecked={index}
              onChange={e =>
                onRoundTripChecked(
                  item.rt_price,
                  item.vehicle_id,
                  item.currency,
                  item.seconds_before_pick,
                  item.max_pax,
                  item.release_hours,
                )
              }
              name="radio"
            />
            <span className="checkmark" />
          </label>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am setting defaultChecked={index}, but it only selects the last
> radio button and the same is true for checked prop.

This is because they all belong to the same radio group (which you have defined in your code as `name="radio"`).

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio#Defining_a_radio_group):

> A radio group is defined by giving each of radio buttons in the group
> the same name. Once a radio group is established, selecting any radio
> button in that group automatically deselects any currently-selected
> radio button in the same group.

Try to give your radio buttons unique names:

```js
const App = () => {
  let sampleArray = ["foo","bar","joe"];
  
  return (
    <div>
      {sampleArray.map(function(value, index){
        return (
          <div>
            <input
              type="radio"
              defaultChecked={true}
              name={`radio-${index}`}
            />
            <label>{value}</label>
          </div>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

---

On a UX perspective, radio input are usually used to indicate a selection from an input group. I can't see your project layout as of this writing, but I suggest you look into using [checkboxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox).

Lastly, I recommend passing boolean values to `defaultChecked` prop. Passing index will fail to set the `checked` attribute to true if you pass a falsy.

Comment: I have done as you said and it worked.but it is not selecting the first radio button and all others are selected. Can you point out the mistake? Thank you so much.

Comment: yes, you are probably passing a javascript falsy. please have a look at the very last sentence in my answer. try to pass `true` to the prop instead of `index`, for example